# Transfer files from S3 Bucket to another keeping folder structure - python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

Have found many questions related to this with solutions using `boto3`, however I am in a position where I have to use `boto`, running Python 2.38.

Now I can successfully transfer my files in their folders (Not real folders I know as S3 doesn't have this concept) but I want them to be saved into a particular folder in my destination bucket

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection


def transfer_files():
  conn = S3Connection()
  srcBucket = conn.get_bucket("source_bucket")
  dstBucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name="destination_bucket")
  objectlist = srcbucket.list()
  for obj in objectlist:
      dstBucket.copy_key(obj.key, srcBucket.name, obj.key)
```

My `srcBucket` will look like `folder/subFolder/anotherSubFolder/file.txt` which when transferred will land in the `dstBucket` like so `destination_bucket/folder/subFolder/anotherSubFolder/file.txt`

I would like it to end up in `destination_bucket/targetFolder` so the final directory structure would look like

```
destination_bucket/targetFolder/folder/subFolder/anotherSubFolder/file.txt
```

Hopefully I have explained this well enough and it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the name of the destination key.

Therefore, just use:

```
dstBucket.copy_key('targetFolder/' + obj.key, srcBucket.name, obj.key)
```

Comment: Thank you John, just getting my head around the s3 folder structure being keys and not actual folders